# Extraction process fails

Tags: system-installation

Trying to create a bootable USB drive that will load ubuntustudio-23.04-dvd-amd64.iso  Using Unetbootin. The extraction process stalls after extracting 578 of 617 files, 93%. I started by using a 32 GB USB drive formatted with FAT 32, Then reformatted the drive using exFAT; next I tried I tried using a large USB drive, I formatted it with FAT 32 and then I tried exFAT. In each instance the extraction process stopped working after extracting 578 of 617 files. I wonder why?

One thing I notice is under Extraction process it says, Source: casper\filessystem.squashfs (4,095 MB) Destination F:/casper/filesystem.squashfs.

What should I do?

KCav

Quote Reply
Report

Comment: did you verify the .iso?

Comment: I downloaded the iso twice - It was the same size  both times.  How should I verify its integrity?

Comment: there should be a sha256 checksum available for download; download it and compare with the sha256 checksum of the downloaded iso. Also how long did you wait once it stalled?

Comment: Where do I find shs256 checksum?  I looked under properties.

Comment: I downloaded Ubuntu Studio 22.04.21 and used UNetbootin to extract contents. It stalled after 578 of 660 87%

Comment: run 'sha256sum -c SHA256SUMS` (assuming both the .iso and the SHA256SUMS files are in the same directory, with their original names). It will say 'OK' if the sums match